# Setting button size according to longest text in the button list

Tags: javascript, css, angular

In my javascript app, I have list of clickable options that I am getting from an api.

I want to adjust button size, according to longest text in the button list.

Setting fixed width would not work, because there will be different option text in different pages.

Below I have illustrated how I want to display my buttons.

Currently, my app shows like illustration no.1 but i need to show it like in the 2nd one.

Could any css trick make this happen?

[image: List of clickable options]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: CSS has no option to equalise element widths that *do not share a parent*. You will require JS probably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use flex

Flex items can share equal widths if they are siblings.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class="container">
    <button>label label label label</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>button button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the display:table option:

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/bjxL1atd/

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}

.torw {
  display: table-row;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="trow"><button>BTN</button></div>
  <div class="trow"><span class="tcell">txt</span></div>
  <div class="trow"><span class="tcell">txt sdf sdf</span></div>
  <div class="trow"><span class="tcell">txt sdfsdfsdfsdfsd</span></div>
</div>
```